# ckfinder Browse Server doesn't work on https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, ckfinder

In my asp.net MVC application on localhost uploading images and videos works fine, but after publishing the project on IIS and test the uploaded images i get 500 server error

Addressing in my ckeditor config.js is like this:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Types=Images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = '/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?Types=Flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=File';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/Scripts/Data';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = '/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
```

how can i solve this on https?

Comment: CKFinder has no problems with working on HTTPS. You should rather check your server-logs first and adjust its settings if necessary.

Comment: thanks j.swiderski , by checking server logs, i found out ckfinder.dll wasn't included.